# How to get window behind dialog box to redraw when dialog is moved?

Tags: windows, dialog, drawing

On Windows, when I display a dialog box (either a custom one, or a standard open/save file dialog), and move the dialog box around over the parent window, the parent window does not redraw, leaving trails of the dialog behind as it's dragged. (The parent window uses OpenGL to draw, but not sure this is relevant.) How do I get the main window to redraw as the dialog is moved in front of it?

I tried adding a call to redraw my main window whenever the dialog's callback is sent a message, but this only causes redrawing to occur whenever a button is pushed or an edit field is typed in. It doesn't redraw when the dialog's window is moved. How can I detect this movement?

Comment: "(The parent window uses OpenGL to draw, but not sure this is relevant.)" - this **is** relevant. You need to invalidate the render context - it's been a while since I did this stuff so I'll have to go digging.

Comment: Windows sends that window WM_PAINT messages to tell it to redraw itself.  Don't ignore them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suspect your opengl app is just using a window for the explicit purposes of rendering via opengl onto it, and then goes into a tight loop of checking for mouse/kb input followed by a redraw of the opengl surface.  An I'm guessing you are not pumping messages after drawing a frame.  And more importantly, that little stub WndProc you setup for your window, probably doesn't have a WM_PAINT handler.

Two things to consider.  Your WndProc for your main window needs to catch WM_PAINT, redraw, and validate the surface.  That is....

```
LRESULT __stdcall YourMainWndProcHandler(HWND hwnd, UINT uMsg, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam)
{
    switch (uMsg)
    {
        ...
        case WM_PAINT:
        {
            PAINTSTRUCT ps;
            BeginPaint(hwnd, &ps);
            EndPaint(hwnd, &ps);
            // redraw your stuff here
            return 0;
        }
        ...
    }
}
```

Instead of calling BeginPaint/EndPaint to handle WM_APINT above you could likely just call ValidateRect.

And preferably, you are catching other window messages in your draw loop.  That way, if a window gets obscured by something else outside of your app (e.g. resize operation, minimize/restore, other windows app takes foreground, etc...), then you can handle the repaint notifications as well.

A typical game tries to pump 1 message per drawing frame.

```
void MainLoop()
{
    MSG msg;
    if (PeekMessage(&msg, NULL, 0, 0, PM_REMOVE))
    {
        TranslateMessage(&msg);
        DispatchMessage(&msg);
    }

    // your code to simulate and render below
    DrawScreen();
}
```

Comment: Thanks. I'm actually using SDL 1.3, and my guess right now is that SDL 1.3 does not pass me window-redrawing events when it gets WM_PAINT events from Windows. Likely this is a bug in SDL that needs to be fixed. I will look into it.

Comment: One question though about the reply above. The dialog boxes I'm using are modal, so they don't return control until they have exited. I don't see how my game's main event loop would be relevant in this case?

Comment: I looked into it further, and SDL sends me a SDL_WINDOWEVENT_EXPOSED event when it gets a WM_PAINT event. However, I get these events only when my window is in the background, and some other app's window is in front and being dragged around. I don't get these events when my own dialog boxes (modal) are being dragged around. Is the only solution here to use modeless dialogs? If so, what would be the solution for the standard open/save dialogs?

Comment: It's useful if another window (e.g. notepad, explorer window, etc) obscures your window.  Or if you minimize/maximize.  But if you are redrawing the entire window on every loop, it may not be important. Also - some Window APIs absolutely depend on window messages being pumped - especially APIs that perform an asynchronous callback.

Comment: How do you get the EXPOSED event?  Presumably by calling SDL_PollEvent periodically, right?  But when the modal dialog is up, this doesn't happen.  Solution: Create a hidden win32 window (an instance of a window class with a different wndproc - in which WS_VISIBLE or ShowWindow hasn't been called for). WM_CREATE of this window launches a timer (SetTimer) to post WM_TIMER to it's own WndProc. You handle these timer events by redrawing your main window (or calling SDL_PollEvent to get the EXPOSED notification). Then DestroyWindow or KillTimer to cleanup after the modal dialog API has returned.

Comment: You can also just use a SetTimer call on your main window. Forget about the need to create a seperate hidden window.